# How to automate application based on command line?

Tags: shell, batch-file, automated-tests

I have a Java based application which I run using command prompt. I am currently testing it manually. I want to automate the process. What tool or scripting should I use?

For example:

1. First I will run the `java` command to run the .java file.
2. My application will give me 5 options. For example
   i. Add
   ii. Subtract
   iii. Multiply 
   iv. Divide.

It should select one of the options and add the number and verify the result with the expected result. All this will be done using command prompt.

Comment: You [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937541/how-to-automate-command-prompt-application) and got an answer. Double posting is discouraged on StackOverflow. If you didn't like the answer, you should have modified your question.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that you're asking for a command prompt solution, but you really should look into JUnit. It will be a much more maintainable solution for a larger variety of test conditions. If you use the command line, you'll have to parse all of the input and output. In order to truly test your code, you shouldn't have to go through the intermediate of the command line (stdin, stdout); you should have Java code that runs your Java code, since it can access the variables.

If you really are set on using the command line, you would have to give us more details on how your program runs. This is just a shot in the dark:

`inputs.txt`  (These are the inputs that will be fed to your program)

```
Add
4
6
```

`test.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
:: I just assume that your program prompts for input and waits for stdin
java YourMainClass < inputs.txt > testOutput.txt 
:: Program prompts for an operation; "Add" is read from inputs.txt
:: Program prompts for values; "4" and "6" are read from inputs.txt
:: Program prints out the result, which is redirected to testOutput.txt
:: Now you have to read in the testOutput.txt file and look at the last line
FOR /F %%i IN (testOutput.txt) DO SET RESULT=%%i
:: The variable RESULT now contains your program's answer
:: Create a variable to compare your actual result with the expected result
SET EXPECTED=10
IF %RESULT% == %EXPECTED% ECHO "You were correct"
IF NOT %RESULT% == %EXPECTED% ECHO "You were not correct"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a batch file. Put your commands in a notepad file and save it as `.bat`.

If they are not native batch commands though you may need to change some things, but you would need to post you commands before I can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Standard input can be fed into java application. If you're using bash it can be done like the following:

```
java myapp.java < test1
```

Where myapp.java is your application with main-method, and test1 being your test input (a plain old textfile).